# UIAlertView and UITextFields not working

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, uialertview

I am trying to direct the user to a new scene if he enters a correct code, but it does not work.  Here is the code:

```
- (void)showCodes:(id)sender {
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Codes" message:@"Enter a code." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Enter", nil];
    code = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 45, 260, 25)];
    CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 60);
    [alert setTransform:myTransform];

    [code setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [alert addSubview:code];
    [alert show];
    [code retain];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView*)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if (buttonIndex == 1) {
    NSString *text = code.text;
    NSString *othermode;
    bernierMode = @"epicmode";
    if (text == nil) {
        //nothing
    }
    else if(text == othermode)
    {
        //go to other view...
    }
    else {

    }
}
}
```

I am using cocos2D (don't think that makes a difference) in my header file, I also set the UIAlertView Delegate.

Thanks,

Tate

Comment: Migrate to gamedev.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Um... why?  I have asked all of my other questions here.

Comment: where i added the comment //go to other view... I have put a UIAlert View that says sothing.  In the else statement, I put an alert view that says another thing.  Even if I enter the correct code (othermode) it always takes the first if statement.

Comment: By the way, you should use `isEqualToString:` to compare strings instead of `==`.  Not sure if this is the only issue.

Comment: Thanks so much!  That was the problem!  I couldn't figure that out forever! I love this site!

Comment: You shoud post that as a answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Gaming - Stack Exchange](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) will be a better site for you. That site is specific to all of your gaming code needs.